# Looking for color codes of the default fill colors in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, colors, hex

I am writing a script that colors cells in a Google spreadsheet using the `Range.setBackground(color)` method. I want to use one of the preset fill colors, but I am having a hard time finding the exact color codes. Hex, RGB, I just want an official list.

[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#000000 #434343 #666666 #999999 #B7B7B7 #CCCCCC #D9D9D9 #EFEFEF #F3F3F3 #FFFFFF

#980000 #FF0000 #FF9800 #FFFF00 #00FF00 #00FFFF #4A85E8 #0000FF #9900FF #FF00FF

#E6B8AF #F4CCCC #FDE5CD #FFF3CC #D9EBD3 #D1E0E3 #C9DBF8 #CFE2F3 #D9D3E9 #EBD1DC
#DD7D6B #EB9899 #F9CB9C #FFE598 #B6D7A8 #A2C4CA #A4C2F4 #9EC5E9 #B4A7D6 #D5A6BD
#CC4124 #E06665 #F7B16B #FFD966 #92C47D #75A5AF #6D9EEC #6EA8DC #8E7CC3 #C27BA0
#A61B00 #CC0000 #E69038 #F1C231 #6AA84E #44818E #3B77D8 #3C84C6 #674EA7 #A64C79
#841F0B #990000 #B45F04 #BF9000 #38761C #114F5C #0F55CC #095294 #351A75 #741A47
#5B0D00 #660000 #783E02 #7F5F00 #274E11 #0A343C #1B4487 #053762 #1F104C #4C0F2F
```

[image: 0]

Comment: You can also take a screenshot and use an eye dropper tool to read the color.