# Difficulty parsing formula for conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-charts

I'm trying to set conditional formatting based on the drop-down value of another cell, but I'm struggling with parsing the right formula. What I want to happen is that cell color in the drop-down matches to the bar chart on the corresponding cell in the project timeline. For example, suppose I change the drop-down in E8 to "crdnl station" and that cell turns "light cornflower blue 1", what I want to happen is that the timeline bar chart in I8 also changes to match the color of E8. The difficulty is that I8 has two colors: one white to ensure the bar chart only shows up (is colored some shade of blue) under the weeks it is relevant to the project.

```
=SPARKLINE({int(D13)-int($D$10),int(E13)-int(D13)},{"charttype","bar";"color1","white";"color2",if(B13="crdnl station","light cornflower blue 1",if(B13="campaign","dark blue 1",if(B13="registration","dark cornflower blue 3")));"max",int($E$10)-int($D$10)})
```

Comment: Please format your post to enhance readability

Answer (score 0):

the formula is correct, but the issue is that `SPARKLINE` does not support official sub-shades...

```
=SPARKLINE({INT(D13)-INT($D$10), INT(E13)-INT(D13)},
 {"charttype", "bar";
  "color1",    "white";
  "color2", IF(B13="crdnl station", "green",
            IF(B13="campaign",      "blue",
            IF(B13="registration",  "red", )));
  "max", INT($E$10)-INT($D$10)})
```

[image: 0]

---

but you can use HEX notation (`#FFA500`) which is supported:

[image: 0]

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/54939337/5632629**

```
=SPARKLINE({INT(D13)-INT($D$10), INT(E13)-INT(D13)},
 {"charttype", "bar";
  "color1",    "white";
  "color2", IF(B13="crdnl station", "#6D9EEC",
            IF(B13="campaign",      "#3C84C6",
            IF(B13="registration",  "#053762", )));
  "max", INT($E$10)-INT($D$10)})
```

[image: 0]